# Connection to localhost by name appears slow on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, hostname

I'm running some code (Perl's WWW::Mechanize module) on OS X and it keeps hanging on simple HTTP `GET` requests against `http://localhost:5000/`. My server is fine, but the response time is measured in minutes.

If I switch it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, the server responds instantly, so it looks like it has something to do with using the hostname.

This is macOS Sierra, running version 10.12.1. `/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255     broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

All of my browsers connect instantly, as does `wget`, but `curl` gets this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/login
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

However, if I switch that to `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/login`, it works just fine.

Comment: Your web service may not be listening on IPv6

Comment: I agree with HBrujin, this is most frequently a symptom of a missing ::1 listener. The application tries the IPv6 address returned by the resolver first, fails, then retries on V4.